# how can i attach visual studio to child process of a process on remote machine?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2008, process

When I run a process on remote machine, say A.exe, it spawns child processes, lets say, childA.exe.

What I'd like to do is, I want visual studio to kick in (hit a breakpoint) as soon as childA.exe is spawned ?

I looked around and figured out, one cannot debug, child processes of a parent process in visual studio. That is, if I put a breakpoint in code and launch A.exe; when childA.exe starts executing, it won't hit that breakpoint.

PS: I'm using visual studio 2008. If it helps, I can also use vs 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [setup visual studio remote debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y7f5zaaa.aspx) in the remote machine.  And do remote debugging.

Comment: I'm aware of that. My question is focused on debugging for the child process that a parent spawns.